# Dynamically allocated array in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I am playing around with dynamically allocating an array in c++.  I have this code

```
#include <iosteam>
using namespace std;

void A(int* arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int **nums;
    nums = new int*[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        nums[i] = new int(i);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << *nums[i] << endl;

    cout << endl;
    A(*nums);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

0
0
0
0
0
0
33
0
1
0
```

My question is:  When the array is passed to the function A(int* arr), why does the array printed there have different output than what the array defined in main() has?  I have been studying dynamic allocation and double pointers, but I can't seem to figure this one out.  I have searched through SO questions and can't find a suitable answer to this question.  I would like to know if I can print the values of the array in the function A(), or if it is even possible to do it this way.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function:

```
void A(int* arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

is getting called with `A(*nums)`.

You are effectively executing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << (*nums)[i] << endl;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << nums[0][i] << endl;
```

You are seeing the effects of undefined behavior since you are accessing unauthorized memory.

Remember that you only have access to

```
num[0][0]
num[1][0]

....

num[9][0]
```

and not

```
num[0][0]
num[0][1]

....

num[0][9]
```

Comment: So if I wanted to print the array in the A(int* arr), how could I do that?  Or is it even possible to do it?

Comment: @jmh: It's not possible, since function `A` received only one `int*`.  Since your data are individually allocated using `new int(i)`, they aren't consecutive and you can't find the other elements from the first.  What you could do is to pass the array of `int*`, as type `int**`, and access the same way you do in main.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you!  That was what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

the answers above is quite right and you can modify your code as follows.

```
void A(int** arr)

{

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       // cout << *arr[i] << endl; or bellow
        cout <<arr[i][0]<<endl;
}
```

reference in your main as "A(nums)";

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I checked this one out and it definitely works too.